# .equals() and == in Java on Integer (== worked but .equals did not!!)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, enums, equals

Code:

```
call.getUserId().equals(ITConstants.SPECIALID)

public static final Integer SPECIALID= 0;
```

POJO:

```
public class ImCall implements java.io.Serializable {
private Integer userId;
```

HBM:

```
<property name="userId">
  <column name="USER_ID" />
</property>
```

MySQL:

```
int(11) is the datatype in MySQL
```

When UserId was zero ".equals()" did not work(returned false) but surprisingly "==" worked(returned true).
I thought it was because of some problem in Tomcat Server.So I cleaned it and restarted.
Still the same issue.

But again after a couple of days,the problem I mentioned above did not reoccur.
But now,both == and .equals() works!

So,my 1st question is,is there any situation when "==" works and ".equals()" does not. 
2nd question is,Why "==" returns true in this case?

Edit :

Getters return Integer only.

```
public Integer getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}
```

Comment: Show what your values are and what the expected output is. I, for instance, am not 100% sure that `call.getUserId()` returns an `Integer`, it *might* return an `int`.

Comment: @skiwi Getters return Integer only.Please see my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly sure there must have been something wrong in your test. The symptoms you describe should never happen.

The only way for `==` not to be `equals()` is if there was a bad implementation of your `equals` method. In the case of an `Integer`, which is a core Java class, that is just not going to happen.

However what might have happened is if the data type came back as a different format (`Float` or `Long` for example) than you expected the `equals()` may have failed there.

For example `3 == 3L` returns true but `new Integer(3).equals(new Long(3))` returns false. That's because the == case with primitives is allowed to promote the integer to long to perform the comparison.

Try it yourself here: http://www.tryjava8.com/app/snippets/52b5878ce4b0f5090255bc17

Comment: Thanks Tim for answering my first question and for the link.

Comment: Hang on, though, that's not what's happening, is it?  `getUserId()` returns an Integer, and `ITConstants.SPECIALID` is also an Integer.  Furthermore, if `==` worked, then that means that they were the same Integer instance, and therefore `.equals()` ought to have worked...right?

Comment: @Erhannis Correct. As my first sentence said there must have been something wrong in his test as the results he gave are basically impossible. However I then explained a problem that gives very similar (but possible) symptoms and it does seem that that was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

*Tim B* answered your first question. I just want to add answer for the second one.

In Java by default there is a cache for integer numbers **from -128 to 127**.

So even if you work with object (boxed) representation of int, `==` operation will work correctly, because cached value will be used instead of object.

Comment: True for Integer.valueOf. Also true for auto boxing. Not true for new Integer.

Comment: OK, maybe I should be more generic. But in this particular case of Hibernate, values are cached.

Comment: Thanks Maksim for answering my second question and introducing to Integer caching.

Comment: He doesnt have enough rep to upvote. I upvoted you tho, feel free to upvote mine :)